# How to precompile ASP.NET with version numbers on all Assemblies

Tags: asp.net, precompiled

**Background:**

I'm precompiling a web application with aspnet_compiler.exe. Everything is working but great but I noticed that the version numbers specified in AssemblyInfo.vb are only applied to the App_Code.dll, App_Browsers.dll etc but not to the individual page assemblies. I'm using -fixednames

EDIT: This is web-site not a web-application

**Question:**

Is there a way I can get the version number to propogate down to the page assemblies without a @Page directive on each page using aspnet_compiler (not a web deploy project or web app).

EDIT: It seems that *some* of the pages assemblies do have the version number set and others don't. for Example:

/Default.aspx(+.vb) -> compiles to App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab72d.dll (NO version no)

/Sites/A/Default.aspx(+.vb) -> compiles to App_Web_default.aspx.cd795919.dll (With Version no)

/Sites/B/Default.aspx(+.vb) -> compiles to App_Web_default.aspx.d30819d.dll (With Version no)

**The Plot Thickens**

Okay, so forget everything above, the version numbers ARE propagated to all assemblies. The problem is that only *some* are shown in windows explorer (both properties dialog and 'File Version' column). But the version is there if I read it like this:

```
private string GetVersionNo(string AssemblyFileName)
{
  AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(AssemblyFileName);
  return an.Version.ToString();
}
```

Anyone got any ideas what on earth is going on?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521125/where-to-specify-version-number-in-asp-net-web-site for a similar question and answer; specifically - http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/01/24/assemblyversion-and-web-projects.aspx

Comment: @dash thanks for taking the time to answer. I've actually spent a whole day reading lots of posts like the one above (and the odetocode link). I know I can convert to web app, I know I can use a web deployment project my (edited) question is do I have to?